# If two thread objects' IDs are equal, are the thread objects themselves equal?

Tags: java, multithreading, api

In Java, is it always true that if `thread1.getId() == thread2.getId()`, then `thread1.equals(thread2)`?

I'm trying to track down a bug in a multithreaded application, and I noticed that it compares threads using `Thread.equals()` instead of comparing their IDs. The `Thread` class doesn't override its `equals` method, so the only way for two `Thread` objects to be equal is if they have the same memory address.

**Edit:**

So far I see two reasons why the answer might be no.

1. `thread1` might have been terminated, and `thread2` might be reusing the same ID. Therefore the ids are equal but the threads are not.
2. `thread1` and `thread2` are references to the same thread, but they're not the same object. (Not sure if this is possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29)

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive
>   long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is
>   unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is
>   terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

That is from the Java `Thread` documentation. So the answer to your question is **no**, because another thread could have the same ID as a previous thread as long as the first thread was terminated

Comment: This documentation is self-contradictory as a matter of fact. Either it is unique or it is re-usable. I suppose it should say something like 'unique when created'?

Comment: I think it makes sense as is :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As Thread's javadoc says:

```
    /**
 * Returns the identifier of this Thread.  The thread ID is a positive
 * <tt>long</tt> number generated when this thread was created.
 * The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime.
 * When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.
 *
 * @return this thread's ID.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public long getId() {
    return tid;
}
```

Comment: That says that the ID uniquely identifies the thread, but it does not say that it is impossible to have two different objects in memory reference the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

When threads are created their identifier is sequentially incremented. They start at 0 each time and are incremented by one for each process that created them. Therefore the IDs are not globally unique.

Comment: The incrementing is an implementation detail.  It could conceivably be different in other versions of Java ... past or future.